# Web.Config Error using Web Application

Tags: asp.net, roleprovider

I use this Web.Config file.
If I use Web Site Administration Tools as "Web Site" all is working great.

If I use the same script as "Web Application" I receive and error in tab "Security".
Error:

"There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where you can choose a new data store.

The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Failed to start monitoring changes to 'Z:\MSDOS_DOCUMENTS_SETTINGS\SWN-Working\Projects-Cms\Cms-Application-ProtoTypes\Admin-RolesPermissions\ProtoType-Rules\ProtoType-Rules'. "

I really do not know what I am doing wrong. Could you please advice me? Thanks for your support!

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

    <!--
      For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
      http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
      -->

    <configuration>
        <connectionStrings>
            <add name="CmsConnectionString"
                 connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DbCmsWebsiteTest;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
        </connectionStrings>

        <system.web>
            <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>

            <roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true">
                <providers>
                    <clear/>
                    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider"
                         connectionStringName="CmsConnectionString"
                         applicationName="/"
                         type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
                </providers>
            </roleManager>

            <membership>
                <providers>
                    <clear/>
                    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
                         connectionStringName="CmsConnectionString"
                         applicationName="/"
                         type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
                         enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
                         enablePasswordReset="true"
                         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
                         requiresUniqueEmail="false"
                         passwordFormat="Hashed"
                         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
                         minRequiredPasswordLength="7"
                         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1"
                         passwordAttemptWindow="10"
                         passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
                </providers>
            </membership>

        </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out solution to my problems.
Solution it is here
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317955